# How to set password for multiple sheets in vba?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I need to set password for multiple excel sheets in vba. I have a excel document with sheets for different company sections. I want that when I open excel document that only start page is shown, and then when I eneter password , if it is correct, then to open only two sheets for that section. Idea is: 
Open excel document, start page is shown.
Enter password for one of the 6 sections
If password for section1 or section 2 ... or section 4 is correct, show two sheets that belongs to section for which we entered password.
If password for section5 or section 6 is correct, then show all sheets. I've tried first to lock one sheet with this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim xSheetName As String
    xSheetName = "Sheet1"
    If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = xSheetName Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
       xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
       response = Application.InputBox("Password", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
       If response = "123456" Then
          Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Visible = True
          Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Select
       End If
 End If
 Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Visible = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Problem with this whenever I click on other sheet and then click back to sheet1 it asks for password ( becouse of

```
                       `If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = xSheetName Then
                               Application.EnableEvents = False
                               Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False`
```

I suppose, but I don't know how to avoid it.
Then , when I tried to lock multiple sheets like this :

```
Dim xSheetName1 as String
Dim xSheetName3 as String
xSheetName1 = "Sheet1"
xSheetName3 = "Sheet3"
If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = xSheetName1 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
response = Application.InputBox("Password", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
If response = "123" Then
    Application.Sheets(xSheetName1).Visible = True
    Application.Sheets(2).Visible = True
    Application.Sheets(xSheetName1).Select

If Application.Sheets(1).Visible = True Then

Application.EnableEvents = False
Aplication.Sheets(xSheetName1).Visible = False
Exit Sub
End If
 End If

End If
   If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = xSheetName3 Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
      xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
     response = Application.InputBox("Password", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
    If response = "111" Then
      Application.Sheets(xSheetName3).Visible = True
      Application.Sheets(5).Visible = True
      Application.Sheets(5).Select

If Application.Sheets(1).Visible = True Then ' tried to get rid of asking                          

                                               for password every time


    Application.EnableEvents = False
 '  Aplication.Sheets(xSheetName1).Visible = False
  Exit Sub
 End If
 End If
  End If
  Application.Sheets(xSheetName1).Visible = True
  Application.Sheets(xSheetName3).Visible = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

then when I enter any correct password all locked sheets are unlocked.
Sometimes I've used Sheets(index) because for some sheets names error 9 makes problem :)))

Comment: Why not use a button on the Start page to trigger the request for a password?  Using the Sheet_Activate event doesn't seem like the right approach.

Comment: (Just to point out, as I'm not sure what your end-goal with the passwording is, but passwords in Excel can be [pretty easily bypassed](https://www.google.com/search?q=bypass+excel+password) if the user really wants.  It'll probably be fine if your users are new/not too knowledgeable in Excel, but if someone wants to get in there, they probably can.)  Also, and I may be missing something, you're not technically adding passwords, you're just making sheets visible or not based on user inputted strings.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with batman, this is not a very secure way of doing this. Best to have this as a master file, and run the macro to split the sheets into multiple files with password.

This way you can still edit contents with 1 file, and still manage the security within 1 file.